# confidence interval formula of gamma distribution?

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, gamma-distribution

i want a help can someone tell me the formula for confidence interval  of gamma distribution? for alpha and beta Parameters i couldent find them?
and there also this problem i dont know which pdf of gamma is correct

[image]

or [image]